# Oracle PL/SQL monitor directory for new files

Tags: oracle, plsql

I will start off by saying I am new to working with Oracle, so while I have searched for this without luck it may be I'm missing the right terminology.

What I am trying to do is using an Oracle database and PLSQL, is to monitor a specified directory and when a new file is added then call a function within the database to process that file. Is this something that is possible to do through PLSQL, if so then any guidance of where I should look would be greatly appreciated.

Satal

Comment: process the file ...?.what exactly you want to do with the file

Comment: @David: I am currently unsure of the version, waiting on the client to let me know what they have installed.

Comment: @Harshit: It will be an XML file which I will be looking to read in the values into tables within the database, although at the moment I'm mostly trying to see if I can just detect when a new file is added

Comment: @Satal I think you cannot fetch files from a directory directly through PLSQL need to take help of JAVA for that.

Comment: According to [this post on the Oracle.com forums](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/957200) there's functionality in SYS.DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE and SYS.XUTL_FINDFILES to do this - but IMO fiddling with DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE is like playing with matches in a fireworks factory.  As we don't have XUTL_FINDFILES installed I can't comment on it.  Read the post, see what you can do.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis - XUTL_FINDFILES is a hand-rolled wrapper for DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE written by Chris Poole.  His site is no longer active, but the Wayback Machine has a snapshot of it.  http://web.archive.org/web/20110104074937/http://www.chrispoole.co.uk/apps/xutlff.htm

Comment: Although I agree with Justin Cave's comments.  There's no way I would ask a DBA to install XUTL_FINDFILES on a production database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Oracle 11g you can use the new File Watcher feature of Oracle Scheduler.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse005.htm#CIAJIADA

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/scheduler-enhancements-11gr2.php#file_watcher

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jeffrey, that was something new.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the best option

Answer (score 4):

To look at an Operating System requires an OS utility.  There are two ways to integrate the OS and the database.

**Drive this from the OS**
The old skool approach is to write a shell script which executes an `ls` against the target directory and instigates a SQL*Plus session to call a stored procedure which process any file it finds.  Use `cron` to call this script on a regular basis.  (Substitute the Windows equivalents of these programs).

**Drive from the database**
The nu skool approach is have a stored procedure run everything.  There is no Oracle built-in for searching an OS directory, but it can be done with a Java Stored Procedure which calls an OS executable.  The Java security model is a bit complicated, but the technique does work very well.  [Find out more](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584).  Write a PL/SQL procedure to call the JSP and process the file if anything is found.  This procedure is executed from a DBMS_JOB, which kicks off on a regular basis.

A variant on this approach, available from 10g onwards is to use DBMS_SCHEDULER.  We can create [a job which executes an OS command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse002.htm#sthref2999) and [chain it with another job](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse006.htm#sthref3079) to process the file if the first job finds anything.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [utl_file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_file.htm) package

also look at this [AskTom question](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584)